# How to include two submenus of same namespace extension in Magento 2?

Tags: extensions, magento-2.0

I have two extensions:

```
ProductPricing

NfusionWidgets
```

Both extensions are in same namespaces called: **Nfusionsolutions**

Both extension have some settings in back end so I have created menu on which admin can click and configure settings.
Please see screenshot.
[image]

I have put following code in **menu.xml** file in "ProductPricing" extension to get this result.

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing::nfusion_solutions"
         title="nFusion Solutions"
         module="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content"
    />
    <!-- START: new node -->                
    <add id="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing::product_pricing"
         title="Product Pricing"
         module="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content"

         parent="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing::nfusion_solutions"
         action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/nfusionsolutions_productpricing"
        />                            
    <!-- END:   new node -->  
</menu>
```

Now I want a new submenu should come just below the first submenu for second extension like below screenshot:

[image]

I have put this code in **menu.xml** file in **NfusionWidgets** extension.

```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <!-- START: new node -->                
    <add id="Nfusionsolutions_NfusionWidgets::nfusionwidgets"
         title="nFusion Widgets"
         module="Nfusionsolutions_NfusionWidgets"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content"

         parent="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing::nfusion_solutions"
         action="cms/page/index"
        />                            
    <!-- END:   new node -->  
</menu>
```

Please note that I have put "Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing" in parent parameter which is giving result I want.

But problem is that if user has not installed **ProductPricing** extension then an error comes due to not found "**Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing**" id.

```
How can I show both submenu if user installed both extension

How can I show "Product Pricing" submenu if user only installed "ProductPricing" extension.

How Can I show "nFusion Widgets" submenu if user only installed "NfusionWidgets" extension.
```

Comment: you can create menu.xml for each module etc/adminhtml folder so your issue are resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **update** tag

```
<menu>
   <update id="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions" title="nFusion Solutions" module="Magento_Backend" sortOrder="70" resource="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions"/>
   <add id="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing::product_pricing"
     title="Product Pricing"
     module="Nfusionsolutions_ProductPricing"
     sortOrder="9999"
     resource="Magento_Backend::content"

     parent="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions"
     action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/nfusionsolutions_productpricing"
    />
</menu>
```

For the second extension

```
     <menu>
         <!-- START: new node -->  
        <update id="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions" title="nFusion Solutions" module="Magento_Backend" sortOrder="70" resource="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions"/>              
        <add id="Nfusionsolutions_NfusionWidgets::nfusionwidgets"
         title="nFusion Widgets"
         module="Nfusionsolutions_NfusionWidgets"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content"

         parent="Nfusionsolutions::nfusion_solutions"
         action="cms/page/index"
        />                            
         <!-- END:   new node -->  
      </menu>
```

If there is not menu this will add new. Otherwise add the child in that.

Comment: I edited something in your code  in module parameter in update tag for both menu.xml and it works